# How do I output the value of dynamic segments onto a page with Ember?

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js, handlebars.js

This is my `app/router.js` file:

```
export default Router.map(function() {
  this.route("food");
  this.route("foodtype", { path: '/food/:food_name' });
});
```

This is `routes/foodtype.js`:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function (params) {
    return params;
  },
  serialize: function (model) {
    return { food_name: model.get('food_name') };
  }
});
```

Hence, if I go to `food/pizza` in my Ember application, Ember will load the above file, with `food_name` equal to `pizza`.

My question is, how do I use this value (`pizza`) in my handlebar file? It currently looks like this:

```
<h1>Mmm, ...</h1>
```

I want to put `pizza` there inside that `<h1>` tag.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1>{{model.food_name}}</h1>
```